# How to customize hoverlabel in Plolty-python?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, linechart

I'm trying to customize the `hoverlabel` in plotly similar to StackOverflow reputation plot `hoverlabel`(like below):

Link to access reputation plot of StackOverflow:
`https://stackexchange.com/users/<userid>/<username>?tab=reputation`

[image]

Plotly code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.stocks()
fig = px.line(df, x="date", y=df.columns,
              hover_data={"date": "|%B %d, %Y"},
              title='custom tick labels')
fig.update_xaxes(
    dtick="M1",
    tickformat="%b\n%Y")

fig.update_layout(
    template="simple_white",
    font_size=10, 
    hovermode="x unified",
    dragmode='zoom', 
    # spikedistance = 3,
    hoverlabel=dict(
        bordercolor="rgba(24, 59, 218, 0.8)",
        bgcolor="rgba(34, 34, 102, 0.03)",
        font_size=14,
        font_family="Raleway",
        # "Arial", "Balto", "Courier New", "Droid Sans",, "Droid Serif", 
        # "Droid Sans Mono", "Gravitas One", "Old Standard TT", "Open Sans", 
        # "Overpass", "PT Sans Narrow", "Raleway", "Times New Roman"
        align="right"
        ),
        hoverlabel_namelength=100
        )


fig.update_traces(mode="lines", hovertemplate=None)
fig.show()
```

Update:
Thanks to @r-beginners for helping to update traces
`fig.update_traces(mode="lines", hovertemplate=None)`

[image]

I'm unable to customize the `hoverlabel` like the StackOverflow reputation plot. Is there a way to customize the `hoverlabel` and hover mode like the StackOverflow plot?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: In between the two images added in the post..

Comment: Where is the code of the first graph, the posted code is for the second graph?

Comment: If I have that code, why would I post this question here

Comment: You should post the minimum code and data to let others help you.

Comment: There is a plotly code I tried and added in the post and there is data `df = px.data.stocks()
`

Comment: The answer is to use the same format in `fig.update_layout` with your first graph.

Comment: Try This: `fig.update_traces(mode="lines", hovertemplate=None)`

Comment: Is there a way to update `hovermode` as highlighting the points in line, instead of dashed vertical line?